# jquery find part of word and change to the complete one

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox that I want replace the words that matches.

For example: find `@jo` or `@j` or `@jos` = change to `@josh`

I tried:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".addname", function() {

var user= $(this).attr('title');
var word='/@'+user+'(\w+)/ig'; // REGEX - eg: find @j

var comment=$("#comment").val();
var p = comment.match(word);

alert(p);

var username= $(this).attr('data-id');
$("#comment").val($("#comment").val().replace(p, username));

});
```

html:

```
<textarea id='comment'>this is a test - @j and @ma</textarea>

<br><br>
<span class='addname' title="j" data-id=josh>josh</span>
<br><br>
<span class='addname' title="ma" data-id=marie>marie</span>
```

but `var p` is null... what is wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/b8skny1t/

Comment: you want this?https://jsfiddle.net/b8skny1t/2/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi oh, yeah, it is perfect!

Comment: I've added it as answer. Accept it if it helped you:)

Comment: @AnoopJoshi can't find your answer here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use RegxP for adding dynamic regex,

```
$(document).on("click", ".addname", function() {
  var user = $(this).attr('title');
  var word = '@' + user; // REGEX - eg: find @j
  var rx = new RegExp(word, 'ig');
  var comment = $("#comment").val();
  var p = comment.match(rx);
  var username = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $("#comment").val($("#comment").val().replace(p, username));

});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b8skny1t/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Is it necessary to use 'Regex'?
You can use

```
var word='@'+user;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the regex you are using.

Try something like this:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".addname", function() {

var user= $(this).attr('title');
var comment=$("#comment").val();
var re = new RegExp("^@"+user, "i");
var match = re.test(comment);
if(match){
var username= $(this).attr('data-id');
$("#comment").val($("#comment").val().replace(comment, username));
}
});
```